# Heroku deployed database empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I am having a problem where i have data in my local database using sqllite3, but i have deployed to heroku (postgresSQL) and the database is empty, which i think is causing some issues on some of my pages. Do I need to change my gemfile? see below

```
`source 'https://rubygems.org'

#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

#gem 'ruby', '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'debugger'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'

end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'


end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end`
```

What I do?

Comment: run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: What does `heroku logs` say about the error?

Comment: I ran the migrate command and still have an empty database and there is no error that refers to anything about the tables. The page loads but there is no data displayed. Do i need some connection information somewhere for it to add the tables to my postgres database?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your development and production databases should be the same.  So if you are going to continue and use Heroku, you should make your development postgres as well.

`heroku run rake db:migrate` doesn't add data already in a local database.  See:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull for pushing and pulling data from heroku.

As far as I know you can't push a sqlite database directly to heroku.  So you would have to switch to a postgres database and then push to heroku. There is a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast) you can follow to do that.

Now the other options is to seed your data. Under `lib/tasks` you can have rake files:

**sample_data.rake**

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    make_users
  end
end

def make_users
  admin = User.create!(name:     "foobar",
                       email:    "example#example.com",
                       password: "foobar",
                       password_confirmation: "foobar",
                       admin: true)
  99.times do |n|
    name  = Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@example.com"
    password  = "password"
    User.create!(name:     name,
                 email:    email,
                 password: password,
                 password_confirmation: password)
  end
end
```

Then you can run

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

To seed the production database.  I believe that this requires to reset your database which ***will destroy all your production data***.  So only do this if you are starting fresh.

In the end, if your production and local db are both postgres you'll have a much easier time going forward.